Flutter and Navigator.pushReplacementNamed: disposal of no longer needed screens
quite new to Flutter and seem to not do navigation in the right way. I took the following route on my screens: Login (automatically disposed) -> HomeScreen -> DebugScreen -> Welcome1 -> Welcome2 -> Welcome3 and then back to HomeScreen with " Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,'/Home',(route) => false);" but guessing from the inspector I created another HomeScreen instead of reusing the old one.
Any hint how this can happen and how to prevent this?
And as I no longer need them I'd also like to get rid of the Welcome screens once they are all 3 finished and user goes back to Home screen (user should be able to navigate between all Welcome screens until Welcome3 is passed).


WIthout more context and code its difficult to say because pushNamedAndRemoveUntil you used seems okay, one question When you complete welcome and reach HomeScreen and do back press do you again reach welcome?

Push the route with the given name onto the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context, and then remove all the previous routes until the predicate returns true.
as stated here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html
It will push a new HomeScreen hence you are seeing a new one.
You need to use
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/Home')); 
Calls pop repeatedly on the navigator that most tightly encloses the given context until the predicate returns true.
As referred from here
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html
